# Intersection of non-NaN entries for pivot table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a collection of SQL data output that I'm reshaping via Pandas `pivot_table` to be row-based instead of column-based.  Each of the new columns will be a time-series with associated datetime index, but the resulting columns may not have coinciding timeseries history.

What's the best way to keep the intersection of non-NaN data for the resulting columns?  Sample data and example below:

**df**

[image]

**post-pivot df**

[image]

And I'd like it such that the resulting final dataframe has start index date of 2004-11-19, per the below.

**post-pivot df**

[image]

Comment: i don't quite understand what you mean by `"intersection of non-nan data for columns"`. but to have your start time index begin from a particular date, set your index to be a `DatetimeIndex` if it isn't already, then you can do: `df.loc["2004-11-19",:]`

Comment: @DerekO, each timeseries starts at a diff date.  I want the resulting df to start at the first date all, three in this case, timeseries have valid data.

Comment: oh i understand what you mean now – thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a series from your post-pivot df that counts the number of null elements in each row, and return the first date corresponding to the where there are no nulls in a row.

I'll create a sample dataframe similar to yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2004-11-16','2004-11-24'), data={'GLD':[None]*3+[0.1]*6, 'SPY':[0.1]*9, 'TLT':[0,0,None]+[0.1]*6})
```

---

```
            GLD  SPY  TLT
2004-11-16  NaN  0.1  0.0
2004-11-17  NaN  0.1  0.0
2004-11-18  NaN  0.1  NaN
2004-11-19  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-20  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-21  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-22  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-23  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-24  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

We can create a boolean mask series that is `True` whenever the number of null values in each row is 0:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), axis=1).eq(0)
```

The first index where s is True should be the start date:

```
start_date = s[s].index[0]
```

Using .loc we can mask the df by the start_date onwards:

```
df.loc[start_date:]
```

Result:

```
            GLD  SPY  TLT
2004-11-19  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-20  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-21  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-22  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-23  0.1  0.1  0.1
2004-11-24  0.1  0.1  0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for response.  Ended up (for the time being) just identifying the start date for the shortest series on the original dataframe using group by as below:

```mindt = df.groupby('ticker').min().date.max()

df = df[df.date > mindt]```

Comment: oh that works too – that's probably fewer steps. feel free to add that as another answer